# iOS Objective-C Set Framework Version

Tags: ios, objective-c

I found a recommendation to implement a framework version like this:

> I have found that Apple's new Cocoa Touch frameworks supported in
>   Xcode 6, offer an easy answer to this problem. In the default header
>   file created for you, something like Framework.h, you'll see two
>   constants declared for you. These are defined later presumably at
>   runtime by internal framework logic. But I have confirmed they're
>   pulled from the plist for the framework.

```
//! Project version number for LocalSearch.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double FrameworkVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for LocalSearch.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char FrameworkVersionString[];
```

However I'm not sure how to actually set this internally in my framework to say `1.1.1`. Could anyone provide me an example of how to set these values? I'm less familiar with how to set a `char` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your framework version inside your target's General Tab, see the attached picture.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work.. always returns 1.0, no matter what I set

Comment: Check your `Info.plist` file and it's also important how you create your `.framework` file.

Comment: I found the solution in a different post, it is the "Current Project Version" in Build Settings